# What does the CSS selector input[type=hidden i] mean?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the [HTML specification](https://w3c.github.io/html/rendering.html#non-replaced-elements) there is the code:

```
input[type=hidden i]
```

What does the `i` part mean? I never have seem a CSS selector of this structure.

Answer (score 4):

It's a new flag in the [Selectors Level 4 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-selectors) that simply indicates that the attribute in question should be compared case-insensitively.